# Is LINQ smart enough not to check conditional flag multiple times?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

My question is, will LINQ in the following code read `flag` value three times when `numbers` materializing `numbers` collection? I am trying to optimize my code. Here I want `Where` clause to be evaluated only once, if `flag == true`

```
List<int> list = new(){1, 2, 3};

bool flag = true;

bool IsNumberBig(int num)
{
    return num > 100;
}

var numbers = list.Where(l => flag || IsNumberBig(l)).ToList();
```

I failed to find a related question. Would be thankful to see how I could check this myself.

Comment: Are you *sure* this will help your performance? Accessing a field doesn't take long at all. This sounds like a micro-optimisation.

Comment: ^^ This, but this implementation does not actually meet the requirement.

Comment: `flag || IsNumberBig(l)` will evaluate `IsNumberBig(l)` if `flag == false` and it will _not_ do so if `flag == true`.

Comment: This is hopefully just a theoretic question, because asking a `bool` for it's value is basically a no-op and it's not even micro-optimisation. But if this was a Linq-To-Any-DataBase query, then it might be worth to optimize. Why C# should skip a `bool` evalution in a loop(which LINQ-To-Objects under the hood is)?

Answer (score 3):

The value of `flag` will be evaluated every time the lambda is called. Obviously, that's cheaper than evaluating `IsNumberBig()` (or some more complex method in there), but still not free.

To optimize this, you could write something like

```cs
List<int> numbers;
if (flag)
{
    numbers = list;
}
else
{
    numbers = list.Where(IsNumberBig).ToList();
}
```

Like this, no iteration is done if flag is true (which in your case would return all elements, anyway)

Answer (score 2):

I think it is important to note that LINQ is mostly syntactic sugar. It does not do optimization. The vast majority of optimizations are done by the compiler, or more specifically, the jitter.

One problem when discussing optimizations are that the jitter are allowed to perform any kind of optimization as long as the result is the same. But it also have to do any optimizations as fast as possible, so it rarely does all the things it would be allowed to do. It will also depend on the version of the compiler, the more recent ones have tiered compilation to get a better optimization of frequently used loops.

Because of all this it can be difficult to guess what the compiler will and will not optimize, and the best approach is to just benchmark the code. Use Benchmark.Net with and without the check, and that way you will get a correct answer. It should also tell you if the performance difference is anything to worry about.

Even thou guessing what the compiler will do is difficult, there are a few things worthy of note. Most optimizations are done within a method, the compiler will not try to rewrite method signatures. However, small methods tend to be *inlined*, and can therefore be optimized as part of the calling method. So if all your code was inlined it would very likely remove the `flag` check. However, one of the things that prevent inlining are indirect calls, like calling a method thru an interface, or in this case, calling a *delegate*. Just about everything in LINQ is delegates and interfaces, and this tend to hamper performance. So in general, use LINQ for convenience, not due to performance.

All that said, modern processors have pretty amazing branch-predictors, so I would expect the effect of an easy to predict branch like that to be fairly small. There is likely other things that have a larger effect on performance.

But the most important thing is **Benchmark and/or profile the code** instead of just guessing about performance. It is common for people trying to optimize the completely wrong thing, even for experienced developers. If you want to get started check out [Measure app performance in visual studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/?view=vs-2022) and [Benchmark .net](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet).

Answer (score 1):

You could do this extension:

It basically wraps @PMF's answer in an extension method, so you can use it like the `Where` you already know. It just takes an additional `condition` parameter, that switches on/off the application of the `predicate`. This comes with the advantage that you can chain it with other Linq-Methods just like the plain old `Where`.

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public static class LinqEx
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> WhereIf<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, bool condition, Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        return condition 
           ? source.Where(predicate)
           : source;
    }
}
```

And then use it like:

```
var someList = // assume it is a List<int> with some items
var shallFilter = true; // or false
var filteredList = someList.WhereIf(shallFilter, l => IsBigNumber(l)).ToList();
```

See it in Action in this [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3cXHbI).

Mind that this would make more sense in a DB-Related (Linq to SQL) setting, since that here is really a micro optimization. For it to show effect, you'd have to have many items and a very costly predicate.

---

One word on your code, too:

```
var numbers = list.Where(l => flag || IsNumberBig(l)).ToList();
```

If `flag` is true, `flag || X` will evaluate to true, regardless of X. X will not even be evaluated.

So, you basically implemented the *opposite* of your requirement.

See also: [Conditional logical OR operator ||](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#conditional-logical-or-operator-)